# New jQuery plugin - What is the best way to get input and feedback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, new-project

I had a need for a certain functionality on my web apps and I use jQuery a lot, so I thought I would write a jQuery plugin.  Since this is my first attempt to write a jQuery plugin, I would really like to get feedback from people, or maybe even get collaboration so others could work with me to modify/enhance my code.  I thought the first step would be to setup a project page (I used google code), but now I am at the point of getting input from other developers.

I won't post my project url here because I'm not sure if Stack Overflow is an appropriate place for that (if it is, I can update this post with the URL) - but is there a website I can post to invite people to give input and maybe help with my code?  Can I use Stack Overflow, or is that considered spamming or advertising?

I hesitated to even post this question because I'm not even really asking a programming question, but it does deal with the development cycle.  I've searched google and I'm just not sure where the proper place is to ask people to look at my code.

Thanks in advance!

Brian

Comment: Blog it and submit to dzone, dotnetkicks, etc

Comment: You could also submit some code and say "Is there a better way to do this?"

Comment: Thanks John - I hadn't heard of dzone or dotnetkicks - I will check those out.

I could post code snippits, but I'm more interested in the plugin as a whole - did I set the plugin up correctly, am I using the right methods, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try the [google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en) and come into the #jquery irc channel on freenode the guys there will happily look over what you have done.

Answer (score 2):

If you're unsure of your code's quality and you want some good guidelines for plugin writing, check out [this plugin-authoring tutorial](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern) on [learningjquery.com](http://www.learningjquery.com).

I'm still wrestling with some of the concepts, but the parts I understand are great.

Answer (score 1):

How about [www.codeplex.com](http://www.codeplex.com).  You could create new project and use the project's built-in discussion group for feedback.

I think people are much less bothered if you link to a codeplex project asking for help rather than your own site.

Just a thought.

Comment: Only if plugin is related to .NET or Sharepoint there is point to submit it do codeplex. Most of jQuery devs and users read the mailinglist. That is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I don't think there's any problem with adding your plugin to the jQuery site. You'll get people using it, feedback, and then you update it as needed. All in one place. :-)

Comment: That's true, but that scares me with this being my first ever plugin - I'd like to refine it a bit first :)